How do I figure out which Jetpack Compose imports to use?
I am brand new at learning to write Android applications, so this is very basic.
I wanted to add an editable text field to the simplest basic main activity. The code below is mostly pulled from this documentation and one Android Studio's built-in templates for a new project.
@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column {
        Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
        )
        var input by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf<String>("Hello") }
        TextField(
            value = input,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                input = newText.trimStart { it == '0' }
            }
        )
    }
}

When I typed in TextField, it showed "No documentation found" and won't autocomplete the template, as shown below.

I typed it all out manually, and it didn't automatically add any imports, but it wouldn't build without me adding the following imports:
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

I couldn't see how to figure that out from the documentation.
When I use Alt-Enter in Android Studio to bring up the autocomplete menu, it doesn't come up with any "Add necessary imports" or anything like that. I wondered if my install of Android Studio was broken, but it behaved the same way on another machine, so now I need to figure out what I am missing.
Almost every example on the web shows the TextField syntax but doesn't say anything about which imports to bring in. It does show the import androidx.compose.runtime in the image below, but you can't just import the whole package, and I don't see how to know to import getValue and setValue. How do I find the specific imports needed without trial and error? Note I'm asking for a general answer, not just for TextField.

Android Studio on Windows 11:

Android Studio Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Build
#AI-242.21829.142.2421.12409432, built on September 24, 2024 Runtime version: 21.0.3+-12282718-b509.11 amd64 VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
by JetBrains s.r.o. Toolkit: sun.awt.windows.WToolkit Windows 11.0
Kotlin plugin: K2 mode (Beta) GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Concurrent
GC, G1 Old Generation Memory: 4060M Cores: 12 Registry:
ide.experimental.ui=true   i18n.locale=


Well, I guess Reddit is one place to look for this information... but come on.... Seriously? Android Studio? This can't be the state-of-the-art... can it?  https://www.reddit.com/r/android_devs/comments/jff2vp/jetpack_compose_am_i_stupid_or_is_the_by_remember/
